# Change Table Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have table which has 15 columns so the table look not tidy and value in column took more than 1 line in the box

How to extend the table width or make table to something else so the value in the table look more tidy and just use 1 line of the box ??

View:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th> a </th>
        <th> b </th>
        <th> c </th>
        <th> d </th>
        <th> e </th>
        <th> f </th>
        <th> g </th>
        <th> h </th>
        <th> i </th>
        <th> j </th>
        <th> k </th>
        <th> l </th>
        <th> m </th>
        <th> n </th>
        <th> o </th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr> @foreach (var item in group) {
    <tr>
        <td> aa </td>
        <td> bb </td>
        <td> cc </td>
        <td> dd </td>
        <td> ee </td>
        <td> ff </td>
        <td> gg </td>
        <td> hh </td>
        <td> ii </td>
        <td> jj </td>
        <td> kk </td>
        <td> ll </td>
        <td> mm </td>
        <td> nn </td>
        <td> oo </td>
        <td> actions </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use following CSS for this

```
.table th, .table td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `th` and `td` `white-space:nowrap` property.